# how do i pass a php variable to < script data-x-y-z =""> </script>?

Tags: javascript, php

i have this php variable `$post_price`, and i want to pass it to that script,

```
 <script 

 data-transaction-total-amount=" what do i put here ?"></script>
```

Comment: `data-transaction-total-amount="<?php echo $post_price; ?>"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `<?php echo $post_price; ?>`

```
 <script 

     data-transaction-total-amount="<?php echo $post_price; ?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is far from clear, but I think you need:

```
<?php
$post_price = 111;
?>

<script data-transaction-total-amount="<?=$post_price;?>">
</script>
```